# Is there a way to cache an array formula used as an intermediate value?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, formulas

TLDR: Is it possible to cache an array, or store an array as a result in a single cell, so as to avoid recalculating it twice in a single formula?

---

Imagine I have defined a function `FilterEqual` which takes two arrays and a constant as inputs and returns values in the first array which correspond to values in the second which are equal to the constant:

```
FilterEqual(xs, ys, z)

FilterEqual := [x for x,y in zip(xs,ys) if y == z]
```

I have data with the following (relevant) structure:

```
ID  Date        Value
1   01/01/2011  3
2   09/01/2013  5
2   08/02/2014  33
3   03/04/2012  91
3   01/02/2000  26
```

I am looking to get the latest value (by date) for a given ID.  In other words, my output should be, in this example:

```
ID  Latest_Value
1   3
2   33
3   91
```

Using my `FilterEqual` function, I can achieve this with the following formula in cell B2:

```
B2 := INDEX(FilterEqual(Values, IDs, $A2), MATCH(MAX(FilterEqual(Dates, IDs, $A2)), FilterEqual(Dates, IDs, $A2)))
```

However, it's obviously really inefficient to calculate `FilterEqual(Dates, IDs, $A2)` twice.  (The whole thing is actually inefficient - it would be neater to grab an array of IDs from the filter and then index them into the Dates and Values ranges - but lets ignore that for now.)

---

If this was a normal formula, and `FilterEqual(Dates, IDs, $A2)` was some value which was expensive to compute, I would cache it in an intermediate column:

```
ID  Intermediate  Latest_Value
1   _             3
2   _             33
3   _             91
```

However, if I attempt this with the result of `FilterEqual(Dates, IDs, $A2)`, which is an array, the cells will only store the first value of an array (instead of the whole array).

**Is it possible to cache such an intermediate array value?**

---

Notes:

- A named formula is not suitable, unless it can be parameterised (there are thousands of rows, so individual formulas for each row won't work)
- This can be done easily in VBA, but I would prefer to avoid that if at all possible, as I find that spreadsheets which overuse VBA are a maintenance headache